# Can I fry an egg in water?

Tags: water, fried-eggs

I loved fried eggs, but I hate all the grease that come with them. I have been told this is like a poached egg.  I don't want to fry my egg in oil or butter. How can I fry eggs in water?

Comment: Frying requires oil or fat, even if only a little. Water doesn't get hot enough before it boils. I'm sure this is a duplicate of an older question, but I haven't found it yet

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58573/culinary-term-for-frying-in-water-without-oil

Comment: Not being flippant here but "frying eggs in water" is commonly called poaching and gives you a completely different texture. Some people prefer eggs that way, matter of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cook egg without oil but don't expect it to be fry. Because frying mean cooking something in oil. You can try these methods

1- Poached egg. To see method of making poach egg [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egdu-19VM5w)

2- You can use aluminium foil. Completely cover your pan(Not non stick) with foil, make sure bottom of pan remains flat. heat up the pan and fry egg without any oil. Leave it until cooked.

3- You can also use ceramic plate or marble plate. Heat up plate in microwave oven about 1 minute. And crack egg on it immediately. If more time needed to cook, you can put plate into oven as per needed(Make sure you pierce the yolk with tip of the knife)

Answer (score 7):

You *can* fry an egg on a non-stick pan without any oil or butter, however you will get a better result with some oil or butter. The reason you use oil or butter is to:

1. Seal the pores of the pan
2. Provide quick heat transfer from the pan to the egg

Water doesn't do either for you, all you'll do is cool off the pan. Your egg will still cook, it just won't add any benefit.

You don't need much oil, if you have greasy eggs you are simply using too much. A small amount of cooking spray is enough, you can also wipe a bit of oil on the cold pan.

Comment: I also use cooking spray and no additional fat to "fry" my eggs.  I heat up the pan , then spray with cooking spray right before I crack the egg into it.  If you heat up the pan with cooking spray in it, the spray can burn and give you an unpleasant taste.